# How to get form input with HtmlAgilityPack without getting a null reference error?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How can I extract the second set of input nodes after `<br>` from the form HTML below?

When I try the following, I get no input nodes.

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
HtmlNode formNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form")[0];
foreach (HtmlNode innode in formNode.Elements("input"))
{
 ...
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="subv1" name="subn1">
  </div>
  <script></script>
  <table></table>
  <table></table>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="v1" name="n1">
  <input type="hidden" value="v2" name="n2">
  <input type="submit" value="subv2" name="subn2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form")` *before you load the document.* The following works fine:

```
public static void Main()
{
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("HtmlPage1.html");

    HtmlNode formNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form")[0];
    foreach (HtmlNode innode in formNode.Elements("input"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(innode.OuterHtml);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```